# Is there a table.cell_merge() function?

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to merge table cells together in Pine like you could with Excel or Google Sheets? I'm trying to center texts within two cells, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It’s now possible to merge several cells in a table to create fancy
> headers and separators. A merged cell doesn’t have to be a header
> though: you can merge cells in any direction, as long as the resulting
> cell doesn’t affect any already merged cells, and doesn’t go outside
> of the table’s bounds.

To create a merged cell, use the new `table.merge_cells()` function.

ref https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-tables-now-support-headers-and-tooltips-29924/

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to merge two cells into one in Pine at the moment.